# What are Gaussian Spherical Waves?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

What are Gaussian spherical waves? and Is it necessary for a Gaussian spherical wave to be a laser beam?

I found the term in the paper [*Opt. Eng.* **54**, 035105 (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1117/1.OE.54.3.035105) ([eprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277580177_Modeling_physical_optics_phenomena_by_complex_ray_tracing)).

Comment: Does "[Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam)" answer your question?

Comment: Where did you see this term in use?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Thanks I think this is very useful.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I found this term in this research paper.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277580177_Modeling_physical_optics_phenomena_by_complex_ray_tracing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "gaussian spherical wave" is unusual and not particularly standard. I would strongly advise against using it without due explanation and justification.

In the paper you're referring to, the term is being used to refer to [gaussian beams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam).